# Gem 5 Memory Allocation

Tags: memory, memory-management, gem5

I have made an x86 architecture on gem5. Now if we run an executable file with a memory allocation code using malloc then will this memory be allocated from my system or a virtual memory given to this x86 architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I think the gem5 makes the virtual machine for any ISA(Instruction set architecture). So memory allocated by malloc function is from the memory area allocated to the x86 architecture. It is an actual memory for x86 but it is restricted to the X86. Suppose 1 GB is allocated to x86 then some area in the range of 1GB will be allocated. Not the remaining memory area used by the OS or Users.